# Query gives empty result because of where clause

Tags: mysql

`Table : tbl_email_scheduler`
Here `date_to_send =  '2013-10-12' AND send_status = NULL`. (At time createing table i have given send_status default NULL)

Mysql :

```
SELECT
  id,
  to_users,
  subject,
  message,
  product_id,
  date_to_send,
  send_status,
  status,
  createdate
FROM tbl_email_scheduler
WHERE date_to_send = '2013-10-12'
```

Gives me result

But when i

```
SELECT
  id,
  to_users,
  subject,
  message,
  product_id,
  date_to_send,
  send_status,
  status,
  createdate
FROM tbl_email_scheduler
WHERE date_to_send = '2013-10-12'
    and send_status != 'Y'
```

it gives me empty result why? 
Pls answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because database server treats `NULL` as nothing, try this

```
SELECT 
  id,
  to_users,
  subject,
  message,
  product_id,
  date_to_send,
  send_status,
  status,
  createdate
FROM tbl_email_scheduler 
WHERE date_to_send = '2013-10-12' and (send_status !='Y' OR send_status IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is not equal in mysql '<>'

Try this

```
SELECT id, to_users, subject, message, product_id, date_to_send, send_status, STATUS , createdate FROM tbl_email_scheduler WHERE date_to_send = '2013-10-12' AND send_status <> 'Y' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Any comparison with `NULL` yields `NULL`.You should use following operators according to your needs while dealing with `NULL`.

`x IS NULL` - determines whether left hand expression is NULL,

`x IS NOT NULL` - like above, but the opposite,

`x <=> y` - compares both operands for equality in a safe manner, i.e. NULL is seen as a normal value.

Answer (score 0):

In your second query you are defining if send_status is not Y.
It means if send_status if NULL it will fetch nothing.

You should try it like this

```
SELECT
  id,
  to_users,
  subject,
  message,
  product_id,
  date_to_send,
  send_status,
  status,
  createdate
FROM tbl_email_scheduler
WHERE date_to_send = '2013-10-12'
    and (send_status != 'Y' AND send_status IS NOT NULL)
```

This will first fetch all non-null results and apply not equals Y condition